# Creating a 3d scene from a footage

Tags: tracking

I am new with Blender. I want to know which skills have to be learned to put a footage of someone talking in front of a camera (with some movement of the camera) in a 3d scene from Blender (any kind of room).

Camera tracking? 3D Integration? Etc.

I checked different tutorial but I didn't grasp exactly what I have learn.

Thank you!

Comment: This will get you started with the greenscreening effect you will need to isolate the person talking from the scene - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp4aWuBeNqQ

Comment: That is definitely a beginning. Then, I will have to know how to put that person in a 3D scene. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try here - it's long, and for an older version of blender, but it covers pretty much everything, and you should be able to translate anything that's different rather easily: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34OGr4Nwj4k

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Look for a series of videos called "track, match, blend".